# how to hide or Encrypt URL in MVC including area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, url-routing

i have 4 areas in mvc. i want to hide id,action in url bar.

**Now it shows like:**

```
localhost:2233/Customer/Edit/SomeId
```

**but i want like this:**

```
localhost:2233/Customer/AXIDYFJKDHF
```

I searching encryption and decryption but get many method. i dont know which one can be working fine. else give me correct solution

Comment: If you do not pass `SomeId` to the method, the the method will never receive it.You cannot omit it from the url unless you were to do a POST rather than a GET.

Comment: If you want your ID to be non-sequential so the user cannot guess what the next or previous one is, just use a `Guid` for the `id` rather than `int`. Other than that, there doesn't seem to be much point in encrypting a URL, since it will be public anyway. It seems like overkill.

Comment: @NightOwl888 thanks for ur comment. i already use guid. i wanna to hide my details in url or encrypt because some controller am passing many variables